# using python 2.7 with kivy slider widget will not display background image on android

Tags: android, python, slider, kivy, buildozer

I'm using Kivy 1.9.2 with buildozer .32. I have a slider widget with a custom background image and a custom cursor image. They both display correctly on my computer, but when I push the apk to my phone (Android 6.0.1), the slider widget displays using the default images.

**from main.py:**

```
class MenuSlider(Slider): pass
```

**from layout.kv:**

```
<MenuSlider>:
    size_hint_x: 0.5
    background_horizontal: 'resources/graphics/UI/sliderbackground.png'
    cursor_image: 'resources/graphics/UI/slidercursor.png'
```

**from buildozer.spec:**

```
android.api = 22
```

Comment: did you include `png` in `buildozer.spec` file?

Comment: Yes. And tried setting api to 19... And installing buildozer 0.33. No change. Ran buildozer android clean between builds as well. No change.

Comment: Are you sure it's `1.9.2`? Try importing `kivy.uix.recycleview` as a test, maybe the build included some cached version or used `1.9.1` from pypi.

Comment: Printing the version to a label widget, I was able to determine that the version I have installed on Ubuntu is 1.9.2, but when it pushes to my phone, the build version is 1.9.1. I suspect this is because buildozer downloads the latest 'stable' version of kivy when it builds the apk. Is there a way to force 1.9.2 to my phone?